# Redshiftで大文字のテーブル名を検索する

Tags: python, aws, sql, amazon-redshift

windows7上でpsycopg2とpython3.4.4を使ってredshiftに接続しています。

大文字のテーブル名にアクセスしたいのですが、`relation "table" does not exist`になってしまい、アクセスできません。ダブルクォートで囲んでもアクセスできないのですが、解決法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますか？

以下コードになります

```
import psycopg2

    class KindOfCoupons:

       def get_coupons(self, cur, names):
           coupons = {}
           for name in names:
               coupons[name] = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM \"" + name + "\" ;")
           return coupons

       def connect_redshift(self):
           conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbname host=host user=user password=password port=000")
           return conn.cursor()

       def get_coupon_used_type(self):
           cur = self.connect_redshift()
           names = ["TABLE", "TABLE_B", "TABLE_C"]
           coupons = self.get_coupons(cur, names)
           coupons[names[0]][0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 標準的な識別子と区切り記号付き識別子は、大文字と小文字の区別がありませんが、小文字で表記されます。
>   [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html)

との事です。